A word to use when something is easily spoken?
I need a good descriptor for an idea or thought being present in one's mind without thought, or as if the idea existed without any active effort, such as one breathes without thinking and knows up and down without second thought. Are there any suggestions?
Example:
I spoke French fluently; it came so easily it was ____?

You need to be more precise than that. What do you want the word to mean. What came easily? Learning the language?

Like magic? Like music? Like gushing water? Like you were born with the ability? Like you'd known it in a past life? Like falling off a log? (Some of these may not have single-word synonyms.)

... it was natural.

Air? Water? Easy? Free? Fun? Flowing? Me? Tailored? Bespoke? Bizarre? Going-out-of-style? Vin-rouge? My-first? Mother-tongue?

Even if @WeatherVane "natural" seems the best choice, you may say "it was  instinctive".

You could use the phrase second nature:

If something is second nature to you, you are so familiar with it that you can do it easily without needing to think very much about it:
I used to hate computers, but using them is second nature to me now.


If a way of behaving is second nature to you, you do it almost without thinking because it is easy for you or obvious to you.
Planning ahead had always come as second nature to her.
It's not easy at first, but it soon becomes second nature

I spoke French fluently; it came so easily (that) it was second nature.

That is exactly what I'd have answered. You beat me to it.

I think second nature fits the bill perfectly. Another word you could try is instinctual.

happening naturally, as a result of instinct, rather than being thought about, planned, or developed by training:

those who struggle to control their instinctual passions
He says his decisions that day were instinctual.
[Cambridge Dictionary]
